# Activity возвращает null

Tags: android, java

После закрытия программы и если запускать программу сразу же через секунду после закрытия, программа открывается, но когда хочу обновить данные в одном из фрагментов

```
        ContentResolver resolver = getActivity().getContentResolver();
```

`getActivity()` возвращает Null.

```
01-16 14:45:48.168    6361-6361/com.example.eldos.callreport W/System.err﹕ java.lang.NullPointerException
01-16 14:45:48.168    6361-6361/com.example.eldos.callreport W/System.err﹕ at com.example.eldos.callreport.fragments.Fragment2.computRepForRecycle(Fragment2.java:239)
```

В чем может быть дело, что-то не удаляется во время закрытия или не создается во время открытия?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читаем [документацию](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) и [гугл](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=android%20fragment%20getactivity%20null)

> Caution: If you need a Context object
> within your Fragment, you can call
> getActivity(). However, be careful to
> call getActivity() only when the
> fragment is attached to an activity.
> When the fragment is not yet attached,
> or was detached during the end of its
> lifecycle, getActivity() will return
> null.

Comment: Сделал так:
 
    Activity mActivity; 
    @Override public void onAttach(Activity activity) {   
    super.(activity); 
    mActivity = activity; }


    public Activity getmActivity() {
    if(getActivity() == null)
    return mActivity;
    else
        return getActivity();
}

Работает.

Comment: @metalurgus Спасибо

Comment: все ракно, если вызвать getmActivity() до onAttach(), то вернется null

Comment: @metalurgus как я понял, его надо вызывать  в onCreatedActivity, я так и делал, но ошибка выходила, так когда же надо вызывать это, я читал документацию и, возможно, чего-то не понял, из-за плохого английского.

Comment: я в onActivityCreated() всегда вызываю, только *после* super.onActivityCreated()

Comment: @metalurgus да я так и сделал, но ошибка выходит, дело в том, что она загружается нормально после перезапуска, но когда я меняю рендж на сикбаре, и обновляются данные, а данные берутся из провайдера, и тогда-то ему и нужен контекст, и тогда-то он возвращает Null, хотя может быть после перезапуска он и не создавал новые данные, а просто взял из памяти, но то, что сохраняю активити, мне помогло.

Comment: Ссылку на активити нельзя хранить бездумно. Когда вызывается onStop() ссылки нужно обнулять, иначе у вас будут утечки памяти. Выполняйте свои действия у нужные момент. Если getActivity() возвращает null, значит у вас проблемы с логикой, и стоит над ней задуматься.